# Generate multiple tags while looping with ngRepeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm aware of both `ngRepeat` and `forEach` but what I need is more or less a hybrid of these two. What I mean is the following:

I have a list of columns in the `$scope`. I can use

```
<th ng-repeat="col in columns">{{ col.label }}</th>
```

That would render

```
<th>Col A</th>
<th>Col B</th>
<th>Col C</th>
```

In the `$scope` I have a variable (`mode`). When this variable has the value `admin`, some admin related html tags are displayed using `ng-show`. Also when this variable is `admin` I would like my columns to be rendered like this

```
<th>config</th>
<th>Col A</th>
<th>config</th>
<th>Col B</th>
<th>config</th>
<th>Col C</th>
```

Is there a way to somehow use `ng-repeat` so that I can render the config and the label column at the same time? Perhaps something like

```
<repeat for="col in columns">
  <th ng-show="mode == 'admin'">config</th>
  <th>{{ col.label }}</th>
</repeat>
```

Or is my only option to create a new list that already has admin columns and gets regenerated (with `forEach`) every time `mode` is changed? What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping both `<th></th>` elements in a div using `ng-show` or `ng-if`?

Comment: @DevlshOne that's not valid html.

Comment: Unless your config and columns are same length arrays I don't see how this can be done without mapping the data in controller first. Create a plunker demo with sample data

Comment: @charlietfl thanks. I'm going to bed now, I'll create one plunker demo tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try using the ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. Something like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat-start="foo in foos">{{ foo.something }}</div>
    Anything in here
   <div><div ng-repeat-end="">This code will repeat and should work</div>
  </div>
```

Refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat for more information.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that part in the docs. I was searching for usage examples and scrolled down the page very quickly without looking at other details in the documentation.

Comment: Anytime., That happens most of the time. Feel free to reach me out if u need any more assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a function that returns the columns

```
$scope.getColumns = function() {
  if (mode != 'admin') {
    return columns;
  } else {
    var c = new Array(columns.length * 2);
    for (var i=0; i< c.length; i++) {
      c[i] = i % 2 == 0 ? 'config' : columns[parseInt(i/2)];
    }
    return c;
  }
}
```

template

```
<th ng-repeat="column in getColumns()" ng-bind="column"></th>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Actually in my code I used a function like yours because I needed to filter out some of the columns. My question was more general question about `ngRepeat` and that's why I used here `column in columns` instead of `column in getColumns()`.